# Javascript Facebook SDK - Post link with FB api for Web issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing an app with facebook api to share post on user's facebook wall but I have a little problem.
If user has already approved application privacy, next time he clicks on share button the facebook api doesn't ask to the user to set privacy of new post.
I resolved this problem removing publish_action permission.
It's possible to do this without remove permissions for application?

Comment: why would you want to change the privacy after authorizing the first time? what is the use case for this?

Comment: Imagine that the user first shares the post by setting the privacy to "only me." Now imagine that the user shares another post but wants to set the privacy to "friends" or "public".
Facebook allows you to do all of this with some setting or not?

Comment: With the facebook's sharer the user can always choose the privacy of posts that is going to share, so I do not understand why with the FB API is not always asked. 
I read somewhere that only facebook graph not is deprecated so I choose to use this but it's really strange.

Comment: users get asked about the maximum privacy level when they authorize your app, and you can´t set any level that is higher later. that´s how it is supposed to be, you should not reauthorize users just to get them to set a broader privacy level.

Comment: So the user can set his posts privacy level only the first time?
Is there any particular reason why he is not allowed to do so?
In addition, there is nothing against in removing the publish_action permission after each sharing to enable user to set different privacy level?

Comment: there is nothing against it, but it is pointless. why would a user set a different privacy level later? it´s a maximum setting only, and it is annoying for users if they need to authorize publish_actions again and again for the same thing.

Comment: _“so I do not understand why with the FB API is not always asked”_ – because an API call happens in the background, there __is__ no one around to “ask”. // The user can change the default privacy for any app under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

Comment: Ok, thank's for reply, have a nice day.